# can client server program run on two different machines

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, java

I have a PC with IP address `192.168.153.1` connected to LAN and i have a laptop with IP address `192.168.1.115` connected to WiFi.

When I try to ping from PC to laptop im getting `destination host unreachable` and when i try to ping from laptop to pc im getting a timeout.

I want to run a server program on the PC and client program on the laptop.

Is this possible?

Comment: How is your LAN and WiFi connected? Without that connection your two PCs can't talk to each other.

Comment: They are connected through router

Comment: plz can any one help with this

Comment: Why you have different class of IPs? Can you use 192.168.153.1 for LAN PC and 192.168.153.2 for WiFi PC? The router is the same.

Comment: @linkid, I'm guessing that you are connecting to a "guest" wifi that is isolated from the LAN. To communicate you will need to be on the same network, or at least connected networks.

Comment: they are connected through router

Comment: Like I said you're probably connected to a wifi network that the router keeps isolated from the LAN.  Can you hardwire into the router or reconfigure it?

Comment: i reconfigured dat too

Comment: i changed the ip address. now LAN PC has ip address-192.168.153.1 and wifi pc has ip address-192.168.153.2..both are in the same subnet 255.255.255.0. still iam getting as destination host unreachable

Comment: can anyone help me with dis

Comment: If you changed the IP address on the PC you need to put it back again and use DHCP for the PCs to get their addresses from the router.

Comment: default gateway in both pc's has no value....

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 probable causes. One is your network configuration, the other is the firewall configuration.

1) Check your subnets. If you're using a 255.255.255.0 for both, they cannot communicate without the use of a gateway.

I recommend you keep both computers on the same subnet, or increase the size of your subnet.

If you change your subnet to 255.255.0.0 on both computers, both computers will see eachother.
However I don't recommend this - as this will give you around ~65532 available IP addresses (If I'm not mistaken). You probably don't need that.

The simplest way for you is to change the ip address to be in the same subnet - i.e. everybody in 192.168.1.x.

2) Check your firewall 
Turn the firewalls off on both computers and run some connection tests.
This will tell you whether the firewalls are causing the issues.

Comment: should i keep the subnet of both the pc same or different

Comment: simplest is to keep the subnets of both pc's the same; unless you can setup a gateway to have both subnets talk to each other... which is another completely different setup :). As the comments above mention, you need to keep the network the same as well. My recommendation; keep 192.168.1.x for both  (or 192.168.153.x for both if you prefer) with 255.255.255.0 as your subnet.